# Issues with downloading a file with wp_remote_get()

Tags: wp-remote-get

I'm using `wp_remote_get()` to download a remote file with the following URL:

```
http://feeds.paidonresults.net/1.0?affiliateid=34069&feedid=M742&template=CSV&CSVSeperator=comma&field_names=ProductID,ProductName,ProductPrice,SummaryDescription,ProductDescription,AffiliateURL,ImageURL100by100,ImageURL200by200,ProductAddedDate,Category,MerchantName
```

Using http://web-sniffer.net/ the headers are as follows:

Connect to 80.249.99.4 on port 80 ... ok

```
GET /1.0?affiliateid=34069&feedid=M742&template=CSV&CSVSeperator=comma&field_names=ProductID%2CProductName%2CProductPrice%2CSummaryDescription%2CProductDescription%2CAffiliateURL%2CImageURL100by100%2CImageURL200by200%2CProductAddedDate%2CCategory%2CMerchantName HTTP/1.1[CRLF]
Host: feeds.paidonresults.net[CRLF]
Connection: close[CRLF]
User-Agent: Web-sniffer/1.0.37 (+http://web-sniffer.net/)[CRLF]
Accept-Encoding: gzip[CRLF]
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7[CRLF]
Cache-Control: no-cache[CRLF]
Accept-Language: de,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3[CRLF]
Referer: http://web-sniffer.net/[CRLF]
[CRLF]
```

Which is great.

However, using `wp_remote_get()` I am receiving the following:

```
Array
(
[headers] => Array
    (
        [date] => Mon, 07 May 2012 19:12:56 GMT
        [server] => Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)
        [p3p] => policyref="http://www.paidonresults.com/w3c/p3p.xml",CP="CAO DSP COR LAW DEVa TAIa OUR BUS UNI ADMa CURa PHY ONL PUR COM NAV DEM STA"
        [connection] => close
        [content-type] => text/html
    )

[body] => Fatal Error 
[response] => Array
    (
        [code] => 200
        [message] => OK
    )

[cookies] => Array
    (
    )

[filename] => 
)
```

I know there is an issue with a `wp_remote_get()` and a remote redirect, but I've used `file_get_contents()` and the purpose built function [here](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/reading-a-remote-file-using-php.aspx) but I'm still getting the same body fatal error response

Does anybody know a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

I am retrieving this URL ok on my test stack, which means that either:

1. Remote server was having temporary issues.
2. Your server has configuration or other issues.

I would try to install [Core Control](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/core-control/) plugin, force different HTTP transports and see if that helps.

Comment: Works fine on my end as well.

Comment: Inside a PHP class method it doesn't work but outside it does. That's mad! Why would it do that? It's not an issue with wp_remote_get() specifically but with all file retrieval methods. I've used a different URL from a different company that is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the problem

I was using wp_kses() to sanitize the data and it was mangling up the URL

It was the totally wrong Wordpress function to use for this purpose

What confused me is the response from the remote server. It the URL wasn't correct that I was expecting a non-200 header response.

Well that is 4 hours of my life I won't get back :(